# Python and Scapy: plain text SMTP session

Tags: python, smtp, scapy

Is it possible to perform the the simplest `SMTP` session using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)? 
I tried to read captured with `tcpdump` using `Scapy` and to send packets, but no luck...

This is what I have

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP
source_ip = '1.2.3.4'
source_port = 5100 
source_isn = 1000
dest_ip = '1.2.3.5' 
dest_port = 25
ip=IP(src=source_ip, dst=dest_ip)
SYN=TCP(sport=source_port, dport=dest_port, flags="S", seq=source_isn)
SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN)
source_isn = SYN.seq + 1
source_ack = SYNACK.seq + 1
CK=TCP(ack=source_ack, sport=source_port, dport=dest_port, flags="A",seq=source_isn)
handshakedone=sr1(ip/ACK)
DTA=TCP(ack=handshakedone.seq+len(handshakedone.load), seq=source_isn, sport=source_port,dport=dest_port,flags="PA")
sr(ip/DTA/Raw(load='mail from: test@gmail.com\r\n'))
send(ip/DTA/Raw(load='rcpto to: me@gmail.com\r\n'))
source_isn = ACK.seq + len(mfrom)
.....
RST=TCP(ack=SYNACK.seq + 1, seq=source_isn, sport=source_port, dport=dest_port, flags="RA")
send(ip/RST)
```

Handshake is successful but what `ACK` and `SEQ` values should be during the session? How can I calculate them?

Comment: I think you will need to be more descriptive in your question, if you want any answer here. Please include examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/scapync/

Answer (score 0):

TCP seq and ack numbers are described in [rfc 793](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) (start at page 24). The whole spec is too long to post here, but basically, every byte of payload has a sequence number. In addition to the payload bytes, there are two control flags (SYN and FIN) that get their own sequence numbers. Initial sequence numbers should be randomized, but don't really matter if you're just playing around. The ack number in your packet is the next sequence number you expect to receive, and the seq field in the packet is the first sequence number in the segment.

So to ack all packets up to a given one, add the sequence number from the given packet to its length (including FIN or SYN flags, if set) and put that in your ack field.